# Gantt-like view/usercontrol in WPF, how to create

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a UserControl, or a View, in WPF, that will be able to show, like in a calendar, days in the header, and a list of users vertically, and for each user like a planning bar placed inside a grid, below the days, that will show how many days the plan is taking. It's something like Gantt views, available from Telerik, or DevExpress, but I'm not allowed to use any paid sources/controls/toolkits. The problem is that I don't know how to start, what are the layouts that must be used, what controls etc.

Like here:
[image]

I tried to create a ListView vertically, with ItemsSource horizontally for every user, but in such case I need binding for every row, even if the user hasn't anything planned for that period, so it will result in too many useless bindings, and this solution is also not adjustable to the screen size, except if you change the number of elements you bind to.

I need to show something only there where data exists, and in a manner similar to the image. It means that I need a container control, that will include the header and the swimlanes over which the planning will be shown.

Also, the width must be adjustable, so more screen the user has, more days horizontally will be visible.

How can I create that? What Controls, over which controls I must use?

I expect an answer something like in the following example:
Container control: ListView horizontal
Swimlanes: GridView, or Canvas
Bars: Simple Rectangles

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

I have found a timeline project. It is open-source, and with good examples.
[CodePlex Timeline project](http://timeline.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Interesting challenge, but it's too broad for StackOverflow. Post the relevant code and XAML of what you already tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would reconsider the third party controls thing; building this robustly will be much more expensive than buying it (depending on your hourly cost).

If you want to build this yourself, you are going to need something along the lines of:

- Content scrolling horizontally and vertically
- Headers in rows and columns scrolling respectively vertically and horizontally, syncing with the previous item.
- Item templates, connector templates
- A form of dependency management between blocks (data hierarchy).
- Routing of the connectors, they need to be in a separate layer because they cross multiple swimlanes. Also multiple arrows need to be merged.
- etc.

The requirements are quite severe, you need a lot of code for this.

Comment: I will accept this as the solution because it fits best my question. However, right now I'm trying to create something of my own. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to second `Bas Brekelmans` response above. There is no way that you can build everything you show in the screenshot (dependencies, zooming timeline, progress, resizing to fit, etc.) in any reasonable time/cost. Why reinvent the wheel when it's already done?

[RadiantQ's WPF Gantt](http://radiantq.com/products/wpf-gantt-package/wpf-gantt-package-features/) is a very comprehensive package which will enable you to implement everything you mention above, including varying row heights, holidays, etc. Take a look at their [online demo](http://demos.radiantq.com/silverlight/) which is Silverlight based, but has features similar to the WPF Gantt.

There is of course a Trial version that you can download.